# put an information in a message mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a flow in which I have inserted a flow reference component. The reference component flow will obviously send a message to my first flow with a result "xxx". I want this result to be put in the header of the message sent.

```
<flow name="CreateAccountFlow1" doc:name="CreateAccountFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" path="bank"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="SOAP" serviceClass="com.essai2.AccountService"/>
    <component class="com.essai2.AccountRequest" doc:name="Java"/>
    <flow-ref name="Projet2Flow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    <component class="com.essai2.AccountResponse" doc:name="Java"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: More clearly how to set the header of a message in mule for a precise value?

Answer (score 0):

Flow-references do not "send messages" per se, so it's hard to understand what you're after. It seems you want the result of the execution of the flow-ref to be placed in a message property. If that's the case, you can do:

```
<set-variable variableName="result" value="#[message.payload]" />
```

This assumes that the result of the flow-ref is in the message payload and that having the result property in the invocation scope (aka flow variable) is OK for you. With the little information you provided, that's the most I can tell you.

Comment: Actually I want the result of the execution of the flow-ref which is a string to be placed in the header of the message sent to the main flow. Knowing that I am using mule studio, I don't know where to insert the line you mentioned thaks David Dossot

Comment: I want to pass the result of flow ref which a string to the message header then use it in my java component. Is that possible with message properties?

Comment: Absolutely. Just use the config I provided in the Mule XML file or whatever Studio icon from the palette that does the same,

Comment: <flow name="CreateAccountFlow1" doc:name="CreateAccountFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" path="bank"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="SOAP" serviceClass="com.essai2.AccountService"/>
        <component class="com.essai2.AccountRequest" doc:name="Java"/>
        
        <flow-ref name="Projet2Flow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        <component class="com.essai2.AccountResponse" doc:name="Java"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>

Comment: This was my XML configuration flow; how should I poceed please? @David Dossot

Comment: Never add extra info in comments but instead edit your question. Anyway, I did it for you this time :)

Comment: If your component implements `Callable` it should be able to retrieve all message properties including the flow variables set in the `flow-ref`.

Comment: Thank u very much @David Dossot but I don't understand very well actually I am still a beginner. I have a main process which will call a reference flow. From the reference flow I should get a first result "xxx" and pass it as a message header to my java component. I should also use it in the method of my java component. When I tried this method public String multipleArgumentsMethod(String arg1, String arg2) { return "Request resolved to multiple Arguments Method (" + arg1 + ", " + arg2 + ")"; }  because I will use the result of an other java component I get a problem of entry point

Comment: OK so I think the easiest for you would be to use the `invoke` message processor instead of the `component` one, that way you can use MEL expressions for each argument you want to pass to your method.

Comment: can I if possible have your email in order to have a chat discusion because I don't have the sufficient reputation for that in stackoverflow

Comment: Darn right, I can't start a chat with you either :( Sure, use david@dossot.net (I speak English and French).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am really grateful. I have just sent you an email.